# Prime factor and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, primes

I'm stuck with the JavaScript code I am using for solving a problem which states:

> The prime factors of 13195 are 5, 7, 13 and 29.
>   What is the largest prime factor of the number 600851475143 ?

(this is not homework, is an online coding/mathematical challenge)

So I came up with this solution:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        // This function checks whether it's possible to divide the prime number
        function al(n){
            // k = 13195 is the number that I have to find the prime factor for
            var k = 13195;
            if (k%n) {
                return;
            }
            else {
                document.write(n + '   ');
            }
        }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        //a and b are just for counting from the number n to 2 to find the prime numbers
        var a = 2;
        for (var n = 13194 ; n>a ; n--) {
            var b = 2;
            //if the found number is divisible, we skip it
            while(b<n) {
                if (n % b == 0) {
                    break;
                }
                else if (b = n - 1){
                    al(n);
                }
                b++;
            }
        }
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now to the problem: This outputs these numbers: "2639 1885 1015 455 377 203 145 91 65 35 29 13 7 5". These aren't prime numbers. I've looked at the numbers and I found that the number 13195 divided by 5 (the last number) gives the first number; 2639; 13195 divided by 7 gives 1885; etc.

What exactly am I doing wrong?

Comment: Project Euler kindly asks not to publish solutions to their problems as to prevent people to just copy-paste results. For this reason I am going to edit your title... while it's ok to ask for help with the code, it would be nice if you would not give away for what it is! :)

Comment: I suppose it's kind of lost war though! There are at least 100 more questions with problem solutions having "Project Euler" in the title, and there's even a tag on SO... I just happened to see your particular one! :)

Comment: ahhsad, don't forget to "Accept" an answer.

Comment: How would I go about applying to any number? For instance, through a `var num = prompt();`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your issue isn't a mathematical one -- you just have a bug in one of your conditional checks.

Change `if(b = n-1)` to `if(b == n-1)`.  Right now, your code isn't actually checking to ensure that a factor is prime; instead, it's assigning the value of `n-1` to `b` (for odd values of `n`) and then automatically calling `a1(b`), so your result is all possible odd factors of `k`.

Comment: Oh my God - I've spent HOURS searching for the error. Thanks man! Did you use any program that analysed the code? I use notepad++.

Comment: @ahhsad Nope, no special analysis tools were used, just a second pair of eyes.  Sometimes that's all you need :)

Answer (score 1):

My javascript solution-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function largestPrimeFactor(number) {
var i = 2;
while (i <= number) {
    if (number % i == 0) {
        number /= i;    
    } else {
        i++;
    }
}
console.log(i);
}
var a = 600851475143 ; 
largestPrimeFactor(a)
</script>
```