# Function to determine largest prime factor

Tags: javascript, algorithm, numbers

I am trying to write a function in JS that returns a number's maximum "prime" factor. For example, if I ran `maxPrimeFactor(57)`, I should return a `19`. However, my function only works part of the time. I have written a helper function called `isPrime` that returns a boolean that indicates whether a given number is prime.

Can anyone spot-check my logic and give me pointers as to where I may be going wrong/how I can improve my algorithm and implementation? Any help is appreciated.

```
function isPrime(n){
    var flag = true;

    for (var i = 2; i < n / 2; i++) {
        if (n % i == 0) {
            flag = false;
            return flag;
        }
    }

    return flag;
}

function maxPrimeFactor (n) {
    var max = 1;

    for (var i = 1; i <= n/2; i++) {
        if (n % i == 0 && isPrime(i)) {
            max = i;
        }
    }

    return max; 
}
```

Comment: "maxPrimeFactor(67), I should return a 19" --- or `57`?

Comment: 19 doesn't divide 67.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find the largest prime factor with Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22804017/find-the-largest-prime-factor-with-javascript)

Comment: @zerkms: But the biggest prime factor could be greater than sqrt(n).

Comment: Also, in what cases does this program fail? I can see that it's not going to do the right thing when `n` is prime; have you seen failures in other cases?

Comment: use i * i <= n as your loop condition, you want to go up to the square root of n, not half of it. also, when you find any prime factor (even a small one) you can divide it out, i.e. n /= i

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 is not prime, so if you pass 1 to the function it will return 1 as the max prime factor which is incorrect.  Perhaps a check returning a value like NaN or undefined may be helpful to prevent invalid values, this depends on if you need to limit the scope of the inputs.

```
    if (n < 2) {
        return NaN;
    }
```

You also need to consider the case for when n is prime. A possible way around this more efficiently would be to initialize max to n, and then if max is never set again, the max prime is n.

```
function maxPrimeFactor (n) {
    var max = n;
    for (var i = 2; i <= n/2; i++) {
        if (n % i == 0 && isPrime(i)) {
            max = i;
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

Since the algorithm only cares about the greatest prime factor, if you start counting down from n/2, you can further optimize the function to return the first prime factor that is found, otherwise return the number.

As the local var flag in isPrime() isn't making the code more readable or functional I would remove it .  (Also, no need to loop to n/2 as no number has a prime greater than it's square root);

```
function isPrime(n){
    for (var i = 2; i < Math.sqrt(n); i++) {
        if (n % i == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: As currently written your isPrime will return true for 4. That needs to be <=

Answer (score -2):

I give U a code written in C++ below:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cmath>

int max(int x, int y)
{
    return x > y ? x : y;
}

int maxPrime(int x)
{
    int mx = -1;
    int curX = x;
    /*i * i <= x is correct, because there is only one prime factor larger than 
      Sqrt(x), it's power must be 1, and actually it is curX after this loop, because
      all prime factor less or equal than Sqrt(x) is eliminated.*/
    for(int i = 2; i * i <= x; ++i)
    {
        while(curX % i == 0)
        {
            /*Here i must be a prime. consider Prime factorization 
              x = p1^q1 * p2^q2 * p3^q3...(p1<p2<p3...)
              the first number that satisfied x % i == 0 must be p1, it's prime!
              and p2 > p1 so I can continue to enumerate i, don't need to reset i to 2.
              curX = x/(p1^q1 * p2^q2 * ... * pj^qj) and i = p[j+1]
             */
            curX /= i, mx = max(i, mx);
        }
    }
    return max(mx, curX);
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    //I suppose n is positive
    if(n == 1) //1 is not prime
        printf("No solution\n");
    else
        printf("%d\n", maxPrime(n));
    return 0;
}
```

This code reaches a worst case running time O(Sqrt(n))

And your code is wrong, because when n is a prime, your code cannot get the right answer.

And your code's efficiency is not good.

If you want a faster code, you can learn Pollard Rho or SQUFOF.